# safari 11 crashing when debugging on web inspector

Tags: javascript, macos, safari-11

Safari 11 is crashing when i open web inspector. Odd thing is, It works without failing if i don't open console panel. My HTML5 application works well in all other browsers.

There is no memory leaks as it is not going beyond 50MB while taking memory heaps. And no use of console methods.

Is this a known issue in Safari 11?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can do to fix this is free up RAM. If I close a few applications and then try it again, it always works. Also after it crashes a few times you will not be able to inspect your device until you quit safari completely and open it again.

Answer (score -6):

Some say it seems to be an hardware issue, happening only when the battery is at 100%.

Have a closer look here:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/92290

Maybe it helps keeping on your flashlight and camera, then establishing a cable connection and starting the web inspector then.

**Anyway: This wasn't working for me.**

**Another Maybe**: Connect via network instead of a cable connection.

***Things that might be too late by now***:

**Advice 1**: Do not upgrade above 10.x and use Safari 10.x along with iOS 10.x

**Advice 2**: Put your devices in trash or sell it anyway and start not to use apple anymore. 99% of my upsets lead to issues with iOS and Mac.